# Getting an "uninitialized constant" error when method is called from controller, but not through console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tiny-tds

[Rails 4] Hello. I am in the process of creating a webapp. This is with Rails 4. Also, this project is not using ActiveRelations or a database. However it is working with a pre-existing M$_SQL DB which I query using a gem I found called tiny_tds.

I am having an error that I have become very stuck on.

Basically, my model is a "Network" class which looks something like this:

**app/models/network.rb**

```
class Network

include Query #THIS IS MY CONCERN MODULE (SHOWN BELOW)

include ActiveModel::Conversion
include ActiveModel::Validations
extend  ActiveModel::Naming

...

def initialize()
    @technology = "CDMA"
    @sites      = []
end

...

def get_sites()
    #Custom query - this calls the Query Module
    @sites = Query.query_avg(@technology, @s_range, @e_range)

end

...

end
```

This class calls a module I created and stuck in the /concerns folder. It relies on the "tiny_tds" gem, which is a gem that's used to query a M$_SQL DB. It has worked amazingly well up until I tried to integrate it with rails:

**app/models/concerns/query.rb**

```
module Query

extend ActiveSupport::Concern

def self.query_avg(tech, s_date, e_date)

    q_string = "..." #custom sql string (omitted for brevity)

    return execute(q_string) #return to calling class

end

private

    def self.execute(sql)

        #This is a TinyTds Specific command (where error is seen)
        client = TinyTds::Client.new(username: '...', password: '...', host: 'x.x.x.x')
        result = client.execute(sql)
        results = result.each(:symbolize_keys => true, :as => :array, :cache_rows => true, :empty_sets => true) do |rowset| end

        return results
    end

end
```

And last but not least, here is the controller calling the code:

**app/controllers/networks_controller.rb**

```
class NetworksController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @network = Network.new
    d1 = Date.new(2014,11,22)
    d2 = Date.new(2014,11,30)
    @network.date_range(d1,d2)
    @network.get_sites
end
```

Now... the above code (in the controller) works excellent when I load "rails console" and I type it in manually there. All the data is exactly what I want.

However, when I attempt to call http://localhost:3000/networks/new (even with an empty view) I get the following error in my browser:

```
uninitialized constant Query::TinyTds

...(inside the query.rb module listed above)...

client = TinyTds::Client.new(username: '...', password: '...', host: 'x.x.x.x')
```

PS. I rand bundle install and verified the tiny_tds gem is installed.

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You need to restart your server,

Comment: OH wow... thanks, that was so simple ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding a new gem, you always need to restart the server. Gems are loaded on the application boot and are not a subject of autoloading.